# Canvas image did not show in android since 4.4.4

Tags: android, canvas, webview

Canvas image in WebView worked without any problem in android 2.3.x to 4.1.x
But since WebView switched to chromium I have problem with canvas image - all I see is just blank background instead generated image. I have issue both on 4.4.x and 5.1+ android roms.
I tried using answers I found on stackoverflow like adding enableSlowWholeDocumentDraw() before setContentView.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
           MyWebView.enableSlowWholeDocumentDraw();
       }
```

Or setting webview to software rendering:

```
MyWebView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
```

Also I even tried to disabling hardware acceleration in my android manifest completely. But without any success.

Current code is quite simple:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private WebView WebViewPassCard;

   @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
           WebViewPassCard.enableSlowWholeDocumentDraw();
       }
       setContentView(R.layout.mainland);
       WebViewPassCard = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
       WebViewPassCard.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
       WebViewPassCard.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
       WebViewPassCard.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
       WebViewPassCard.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
       WebViewPassCard.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
       WebViewPassCard.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/passwordcard.html");
```

Assets can be found here: https://github.com/cryptofuture/PassCard/tree/master/assets

**Errors in LogCat:**
Android 5.x+:
*art: Attempt to remove local handle scope entry from IRT, ignoring
AwContents: onDetachedFromWindow called when already detached. Ignoring
Choreographer: Skipped 52 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.*
Android 4.4.x:
*AwContents: nativeOnDraw failed; clearing to background color.*